# Javascript RegExp non sequential characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this rule

```
var reg = new RegExp('[a-z]{3}');
```

Which means it is allowed to use characters between a-z and at least 3 occurrences.
So, I am wondering if there is a way to match this rule with non sequential characters.

In other words,

```
"abc" => valid
"aaa" => not valid
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is "aba" supposed to be valid, or do you want no character to be used more than once? (Also, I'd describe "abc" as sequential characters, and "aaa" as repeated characters.)

Comment: `{3}` is *exactly* 3 characters, `{3,}` would be *at least* 3.

Comment: and you probably need anchors too `^...$`, because I don't think you want to accept 3 characters of a 4 letter string or do you?

Comment: Please give more examples of what is to be accepted and what is not to be, and clarify your question to describe what you mean by "non-sequential" characters?

Comment: Thank you guys, but my issue was solved with below solution. 

@torazaburo
"abc" => valid
"aaa" => not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working regex for exactly 3 (or N) characters, if the number is not fixed it gets more complicated:

```
^([a-z])(?!\1{2})[a-z]{2}$
1   2    3 4  5    6   7 8
```

Explanation:

1. `^` matches the beginning of the string
2. `([a-z])` match one of the accepted characters and save it (group 1)
3. `(?!...)` negative lookahead, what is in those brackets is not accepted
4. `\1` reference to the first group (first character here)
5. `{2}` repeated exactly twice
6. `[a-z]` the accepted characters
7. `{2}` repeated exactly twice
8. `$` matches the end of the string

[Link here](https://regex101.com/r/rK5cV1/2) (I added the `gm` modifiers, so that several expressions can be tested.)

Comment: Awesome man! For anyone that wants to make it case insensitive and include numbers from anywhere between 2-11 characters.^(\w)(?!\1{2})\w{1,10}$ Very impressive regex sir!

Comment: @SteveKline Thanks. I think your regex checks, that the first character is not repeated three times, if you would like to check it at any position for any length, then it gets really tricky (don't know if it is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the excluding lookahead `(?![a-z]{3})`, it will **not** match 3 equal characters in sequence.